# running python script file contained inside a .jar

Tags: java, spring-boot, executable

I am trying to execute a python script that is contained inside .jar. It's works at Eclipse environment but later when try to run from console with java -jar my.jar it failed because it doesn't find the path for file:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [test.py] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: jar:file:
```

In java i am using this:

```
        File file = resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:test.py").getFile();

        map.put("file", file.getPath());

        CommandLine commandLine = new CommandLine("python.exe");
        commandLine.addArgument("${file}");
        commandLine.addArgument("-e");
        commandLine.addArgument("env");
        commandLine.addArgument("-i");
        commandLine.addArgument("'" + id + "'");

        commandLine.setSubstitutionMap(map);
```

I have found answers that recommend that i don't have to use  this `resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:test.py").getFile();` but `resource.getInputStream()`. How can i convert this inputstream to a File object to execute it later?

Comment: Simply create a copy of it (probably a temporary one) and run it just like any other file.

Comment: worked for me copying file to a tmp folder and execute from there. Thanks @GeorgeZ.

Comment: I added my comment as answer. Consider [accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) in order to let other users know that the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 1):

You can not run/open a file that is inside a `.jar`. In order to run it you will have to copy it, probably in a temporary folder and run it from there. An example where desktop opens an image which is inside `.jar`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String pathOfImageInsideJar = Test.class.getResource("/test/example/image.jpg").getFile();
    File imageInsideJar = new File(pathOfImageInsideJar);
    File tempExport = File.createTempFile("tempimage", ".jpg");
    tempExport.deleteOnExit();
    Files.copy(imageInsideJar.toPath(), tempExport.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
    Desktop.getDesktop().open(tempExport);
}
```